How does whole house water conditioner / filtration work?
Intro/Background
Hi All, need help on understanding water conditioner. I had a home depot personnel to do some water testing and said our water is 12 on the level of hardness. Recommended Water Softener. I do want my water to be softened as me and my son has developed skin roughness issues in past year (reason being consistent swimming in community pool). I myself am not very keen on using softener because of added sodium/potassium. Could not find long term effects of it.
Our water district does not allow / prohibit putting whole house water softener. Link for rules and regulations 4th Question in FAQ
Based on my reading on the internet closed thing to Water softener is water conditioner. They way water conditioner works is, it crystalizes the minerals (calcium magnesium zinc etc) because which it does not get stuck the piping. All the companies making conditioner claim it is good for skin and hair apart from being good for your house plumbing.
Question

Does water treated by water conditioner really feels soft on skin and hair?

If there is a filtering stage after my water conditioner then would it remove some of those crystalized minerals?


Edit

as @MTA mentioned, I am worried about sodium because we have family history of High BP and our food is always high in salt.
Added link for the water district


People say they feel cleaner and clothes feel softer with water softener/conditioner.  I think the sodium/potassium stays in the tank and binds the the other chemicals to it.  Skin roughness might be from the amount of chlorine used in the pool.

If chlorine is the problem then most water filter should work for my issue isn't it?

Pool chlorine needs to be washed off, soon after swimming.

@crip659 The sodium or potassium ends up in the softened water. Calcium and/or magnesium, the hardness ions, bind to the ion exchange resin in the water softener, which releases the sodium or potassium from the previous regeneration into the household water. (That's why they call it ion exchange! ;-) People on a sodium restricted diet who have very hard water use the much more expensive potassium chloride for regeneration instead of cheap sodium chloride to reduce their dietary sodium. Alternatively, they use cheaper salt and an RO filter after softening for near zero sodium.
